# Finding a posterior distribution from a Poisson likelihood function and a uniform prior distribution

Tags: posterior

If a counting experiment gives one observation $x=5$, and if the prior distribution is given as a uniform function, then is the following a correct way of calculating the posterior function?

First, the posterior can be written as
$f(\theta|x) \propto f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta) $

where $\pi(\theta)$ is the prior and $f(x|\theta)$ is the likelihood function.

Given that $\pi(\theta)=constant$, $f(x|\theta)= \frac{e^{-x}x^{\theta}}{\theta!}$,

$f(\theta|x) = k\frac{e^{-x}x^{\theta}}{\theta!} $

Since $\Sigma_{\theta=0}^{\infty} k\frac{e^{-x}x^{\theta}}{\theta!} =1$, $k=1$.

Then

$f(\theta|x=5) = \frac{e^{-5}5^{\theta}}{\theta!} $

Comment: Neither $\pi$ nor $f$ are probability density functions.

Comment: @whuber Do you mean that they don't have to be normalized, or were you trying to correct terminology?

Comment: Neither is normalized.  You explicitly claim $f$ is (but it's not) and it's crucial to (at a minimum) specify the domain of $\pi,$ because it's highly ambiguous.

Comment: You are finding the constant of integration by summing over $\theta$ from $0$ to $\infty$.  Is $0$ really a valid value for $\theta$?  Do you really mean to have the prior on $\theta$ allow for only integer values of $\theta$?  Note that your prior, as @whuber observes, doesn't integrate to one.

Answer (score 1):

Your specified sampling density for the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is incorrect (you have switched the observed value with the parameter).  As whuber points out in the comments, you have also been a bit sloppy with specifying the domain and normalisation in some parts.  Your model with a single observation $x$ should give likelihood and (improper) prior:

$$L_x(\theta) = \theta^x e^{-\theta} \mathbb{I}(\theta > 0)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\pi(\theta) \propto \mathbb{I}(\theta>0).$$

Hence, your posterior should be a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution):

$$\pi(\theta|x) \propto \theta^x e^{-\theta} \mathbb{I}(\theta>0) \propto \text{Ga}(\theta| x+1,1).$$